# "Insecure HTTP requests not permitted. Use HTTPS." when trying to retrieve user with gdata 2.0.16 python library

Tags: python, https, gdata

I'm trying to retrieve a user with the following code found in the [gdata provisioning api documentation](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/provisioning_API_v2_developers_guide.html#RetrieveAccountPython). I'm attempting this for a `django 1.3` app, running `gdata-2.0.16` in `python2.7`:

```
from gdata.apps import client
from myapp import settings
client = client.AppsClient(domain=settings.GOOGLE_ADMIN_DOMAIN)
client.ClientLogin(email=settings.GOOGLE_ADMIN_EMAIL, password=settings.GOOGLE_ADMIN_PASSWORD, source='apps')
user_account = client.RetrieveUser('user_name')
```

For privacy, I changed the actual username to `'user_name'`, but that's the general gist of the code.

When the interpreter gets to the last line in the code above, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdata/apps/client.py", line 182, in RetrieveNickname
    return self.GetEntry(uri, desired_class=gdata.apps.data.NicknameEntry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdata/client.py", line 652, in get_entry
    desired_class=desired_class, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdata/client.py", line 319, in request
    RequestError)
RequestError: Server responded with: 403, <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Insecure HTTP requests not permitted.  Use HTTPS.</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Insecure HTTP requests not permitted.  Use HTTPS.</H1>
<H2>Error 403</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I can't find anything in the documentation on using HTTPS instead of HTTP. What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After creating the client object, execute `client.ssl = True`. This will cause the gdata api to use a secure connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try patch attached to [Comment 3](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/issues/detail?id=416#c3) of the issue *AppsService in Marketplace - SSL issues*

Answer (score 0):

adding the line after the client authentication helps 
client.ssl=True.